# join me trae mas datos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy realizando una consulta a 2 tablas la tabla principal t_persona tiene 128176 registros y la tabla t_evaluacion tiene 135839
la tabla evaluacion puede tener varias veces el codigo de la persona ya que una persona puede tener 1 o mas evaluaciones
lo que necesito hacer es que al hacer el join con la tabla t_evaluacion me traiga el ultimo  registro de cada persona que esta en t_personas (128176) pero al hacerlo me trae 135873, me trae mas registros que el total de la tabla evaluacion.

Tabla  Personas:

```
codigo_persona character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  id character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('vulnerabilidad.t_persona_id_seq'::regclass),
  nombres_apellidos character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  cedula character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  fecha_nacimiento date NOT NULL,
  edad integer NOT NULL,
  genero integer NOT NULL,
  meses integer,
  dias integer,
```

De esta tabla solo necesito las columnas de edad, meses, dias, genero

tabla Evaluacion

```
codigo_evaluacion character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  codigo_persona character varying(12) NOT NULL,
  codigo_descripcion_situacion integer NOT NULL,
  cbi integer NOT NULL,
  peso double precision NOT NULL,
  talla double precision NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
  embarazo character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  fecha_abordaje date NOT NULL,
  codigo_origen character varying(12),
  CONSTRAINT codigo_evaluacion PRIMARY KEY (codigo_evaluacion),
  CONSTRAINT t_estado_nutricional_t_evaluacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (codigo_descripcion_situacion)
      REFERENCES vulnerabilidad.t_estado_nutricional (codigo_descripcion_situacion) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT t_persona_t_evaluacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (codigo_persona)
      REFERENCES vulnerabilidad.t_persona (codigo_persona) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
```

De esta tabla necesito las columnas cbi, peso, talla, codigo_descripcion_situacion, embarazo, codigo_origen

al realizar el join de la tabla personas a la tabla evaluacion y llamar al campo embarazo me trae todos los resgistros de la tabla evaluacion, pero solo necesito el ultimo registro agregado

este es el codigo

```
select * from vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion as e right join  
    vulnerabilidad.t_persona as p on p.codigo_persona = e.codigo_persona
```

le coloco un distinct al codigo_persona en la tabla evaluacion y me trae 128176 registros, al traer otra columna de la tabla evaluacion me trae registros de mas

aca el codigo

```
select distinct(e.codigo_persona), e.embarazo from 
    vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion as e left join vulnerabilidad.t_persona as p 
    on p.codigo_persona = e.codigo_persona
```

Comment: Que pasa si usas el `left join` sin `distinct`?

Comment: me trae 135839 registros

Comment: Que no es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: No entiendo tu planteamiento. Hablas de *contar*  y no veo que uses ninguna función de agrupación como `COUNT`

Comment: no es un conteo necesito traer la cantidad de las personas de la tabla t_persona y sus respectivas evaluaciones, pero solo sea 1 evaluacion d por cada personas, al hacer el join si la persona tiene 2 o mas evaluaciones me las trae

Comment: "solo una evaluación por cada persona" ¿Y qué parte de tu select implementa esa restricción?

Comment: Será mejor que nos pongas un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener porque te dices y te contradices. No quieres un conteo pero quieres saber *la cantidad de personas que...*. Yo eso lo conozco por conteo. Da ejemplo de cómo están los datos y del resultado esperado.

Comment: A ver.. dices: `"y sus respectivas evaluaciones, pero solo sea 1 evaluacion d por cada personas"`, bien.. y cual sería la condición para determinar cual de las `n` evaluaciones vamos a mostrar?

Comment: necesitaria la ultima evaluacion registrada para cada persona

Comment: Muy bien, y dónde sale esa información?  de que columna? de tu pregunta no se puede saber. Te sugiero que agregues la estructura de las tablas a la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la `pk` para `t_evaluacion` es la columna `id`, la consulta para obtener la última fila para cada `codigo_persona` podría ser algo así:

```
select  t1.*
    from vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion as t1
    inner join (select  codigo_persona,
                max(id) as id
            from vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion 
            group by codigo_persona
        ) as t2
        on t2.codigo_persona = t1.codigo_persona
        and t2.id = t1.id
```

**Importante**: esto funciona siempre que el `id` sea efectivamente incremental, es decir cada nueva fila le corresponda un `id` mayor al anterior, entonces podremos decir que el `id=2` es más nuevo que el `id=1`.

Ahora tu consulta podría aprovechar la consulta anterior para hacer algo como esto:

```
select  e.codigo_persona, 
        e.embarazo 
    from  vulnerabilidad.t_persona p
    left join (select   t1.*
            from vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion  as t1
            inner join (select  codigo_persona,
                        max(id) as id
                    from vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion 
                    group by codigo_persona
                ) as t2
                on t2.codigo_persona = t1.codigo_persona
                and t2.id = t1.id
        ) e
        on p.codigo_persona = e.codigo_persona
```

Comment: me fuinciono perfectamente, el detalle es que necesito hacer join a 3 tablas mas, donde deberia de colocar los join restantes

Comment: @AngelGutierrez Como cualquier `join`, considera que cuando hacemos `left join ( <subconsulta> )` lo que está entre paréntesis, aunque sea un código complejo,  es como cualquier tabla más, por lo que en nuestro caso, cualquier `join` lo puedes agregar a continuación del código de mi respuesta.

Comment: al realizar otro join en la consulta me trae mas registros, al finalizar su ejemplo coloco el join de la siguiente manera:

Comment: left join vulnerabilidad.t_ubicacion_personas as up on p.codigo_persona = up.codigo_persona

Comment: @AngelGutierrez, si un persona tiene más de una ubicación en `t_ubicacion_personas` tendrás una situación similar a la de tu pregunta (duplicidad de registros).

Answer (score 0):

Mi consejo es que no uses el `distinct` por que así estás jalando datos diferentes que los que puedes obtener con el `select` sencillo, inténtalo así:

```
select e.codigo_persona, e.embarazo from 
    vulnerabilidad.t_evaluacion as e left join vulnerabilidad.t_persona as p 
    on p.codigo_persona = e.codigo_persona;
```

Comment: Esto no soluciona el problema descrito.